# Segmentation fault for recursive function in C

Tags: c, recursion, infinite-loop

The recursive function `FastExp` computes (a^n)(mod m) using the algorithm :

- a^n = 1, if n=0;
- a^n = [a^(n/2)]^2, if n is even; and
- a^n = a(a^[(n-1)/2])^2 if n is odd.

Now I'm sure the algorithm is correct and I followed it exactly, but I get a segmentation fault when I try to run my code. Here's my code -

```
`#include <stdio.h>

/* function prototype */
int FastExp(int a, int n, int m);

/* There is no error in the main function */  
int main()
{
    int a, n, m;

    printf("Enter three positive numbers a n m: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &n, &m);
    printf("%d^%d(mod %d) is %d\n", a, n, m, FastExp (a, n, m));

    return 0;
}


/*
 * FastExp(a, 0, m) is 1.
 * FastExp(a, 1, m) is a.
 * x = FastExp(a, n/2, m)
 * FastExp(a, n, m) is x2(mod m) if n is even
 * FastExp(a, n, m) is x2a(mod m) if n is odd
 */

/* There is some error in this function */
int FastExp(int a, int n, int m) 
{ 

    int an;

    if (n == 0)
    {
        an = 1;
        return an;
    }
    //even  
    if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        an = FastExp (a, n/2, m);       // an = a^(n/2)
        an = FastExp (an, 2, m);        // an = [a^(n/2)]^2
        return an;
    }   
    // odd
    if (n % 2 == 1)
    {
        an = FastExp (a, (n-1)/2, m);   // an = a^[(n-1)/2]
        an = FastExp (an, 2, m);        // an = {a^[(n-1)/2]}^2
        an = an*a;
        return an;
    } 

    return (an % m);

}
```

I'm guessing it runs into an infinite loop, but I'm not really sure how to correct this. Am I making some basic error? Can anyone explain how to correct it with the least number of instruction changes?

Answer (score 3):

You have the recursive call `FastExp (an, 2, m)`. That leads to *infinite recursion*.

It's infinite because in the recursive call `n` is even so you call `FastExp (an, 2, m)`. And in that call `n` is even so you call `FastExp (an, 2, m)`. And so on.

Answer (score 3):

You fail to stop the recursion in the cases when `n == 1` and `n == 2`.

I don't quite understand your code...  From reading the comments for FastExpr, I arrive at this result, which is quite different.  Am I missing something here?

```
/*
 * FastExp(a, 0, m) is 1.
 * FastExp(a, 1, m) is a.
 * x = FastExp(a, n/2, m)
 * FastExp(a, n, m) is x2(mod m) if n is even
 * FastExp(a, n, m) is x2a(mod m) if n is odd
 */
int FastExp(int a, int n, int m)
{
  int x;
  if (n == 0) return 1;
  if (n == 1) return a;
  x = FastExpr(a, n / 2, m);        // <-- Good. Converges to zero.
  x *= x;
  return (n & 1) ? ((x * a) % m) : (x % m);
}
```

Comment: Your code honestly seems like a much simpler implementation of the application, but for some reason it doesn't give the right output. For example, (3^2)(mod 4) gives 3 instead of 1, and (3^10)(mod 5) gives 4 instead of 2. I'm not sure why. However your suggestion of including the cases for n==1 and n==2 worked in my code!

Comment: I had even and odd mixed.  fixed now.  But I don't really know what the application is.  I just went by your comments.

Comment: The application was just to compute the required expression using the fast exponential algorithm.